# How to rename files listed at listbox?

Tags: vba, combobox, listbox, file-rename

I'm trying to create a little program thats introduce some prefixes into the name of the files that found at a folder.

The names of files are listed at a Listbox1 and the prefixes are choosed at a several Comboboxes.

This names of the Listbox1 with the choosed prefixes of the Comboboxes are moved to a Listbox2 pressing a buttom "*>>>*".
When all of new names are ready at this Listbox2 will be press a buttom "*Rename*" and the names of files at the folder will be changed according fixed at the Listbox2.

All of the Userform is already programmed. **I have just problems to build the code for the buttom "*Rename*". 
In others Words, taking the stipulate names of the Listbox2 and changing the names at the respective files showed before at the Listbox1.**
How i can read the new names of files from a Listbox and introduce to the respective name of file?

[Userform Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSbCc.png)

Code:

```
Sub cmdMoveSelLeft_Click()
    'Variable Declaration
    Dim iCnt As Integer

    'Move Selected Items from Listbox1 to Listbox2
    For iCnt = 0 To Me.ListNewFiles.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListNewFiles.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
            Dim changedName As String
            changedName = Me.ComboBoxKategorie.Value + "_" +         Me.ComboBoxTyp.Value + "_" + Me.ListNewFiles.List(iCnt)
        Me.ListChangedFiles.AddItem changedName
        End If
    Next

    For iCnt = Me.ListNewFiles.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListNewFiles.Selected(iCnt) = True Then
            Me.ListNewFiles.RemoveItem iCnt
        End If
    Next
    ComboBoxKategorie = ""
    ComboBoxTyp = ""
    TextBoxEXX = ""
    TextBoxUX = ""
    TextBoxTrakt = ""
    TextBoxGebaude = ""
    TextBoxSpecific = ""    



Sub cmdRename_Click()

Dim Msg = 'Möchten Sie fortfahern?'

   Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt)

   If Response = vbYes Then    ' User chose Yes.

        ~?????????????~

        MsgBox "Die Namen sind angepasst" & vbCrLf
        Unload Me
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what code have you written so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Name` keyword like

```
Name "C:\Post IN\BEISPEIL_SAN_SP_U2" As "C:\Post IN\AUS_BPH_BEISPEIL_SAN_SP_U2"
```

Of course you won't use string literals like that, but I can't tell where you have the old name and the new name. Generally, the syntax is

```
Name "FullPathOfExistingName" As "FullPathOfNewName"
```